# How to diagnose problems with internet radio stations?

Tags: rhythmbox, streaming, internet-radio

I'm trying to listen to the internet radio station at `http://s11.myradiostream.com:32034/`.  I've tried adding this using the "New Internet Radio Station" dialog (via Ctrl-I), however I hear nothing, and there's no feedback to indicate what's going on.  (I was expecting an error message, new radio station appearing in the "Library" list on the left, etc.)

The same internet radio station works fine with Banshee, so I don't think it's a problem with the stream itself.

How can I diagnose this problem?